# How to setup flutter_socket_io plugin to work on iOS

Tags: ios, socket.io, flutter

I'm trying to listen for events from a socketio server in flutter using the [flutter_socket_io](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_socket_io) plugin. i have followed the guide on plugin page and successfully working on Android. However on iOS im getting an Exception

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method socketInit on channel flutter_socket_io)

I have also copied the SocketObj folder to `ios/Runner` as mentioned on the readme of the plugin. However, there is no AppDeligate.m file in the projects io/Runner folder, only AppDelegate.swift is present. I Believe this happens because i chose to add swift support when creating the project. Please help.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. I managed to get around every other problem except this. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @JoãoSoares i switched to using (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/adhara_socket_io) instead. it seems to be working fine on Ios and android and does not require copying any files.

Comment: the adhara one doesn't have a method to disconnect the sockets. If you keep doing hot restarts, it keeps making new connections without killing the old ones. Have you not had that issue?

Comment: @Joao Soares, I had that issue.  To work around, I create a timer(10 seconds) in the flutter app, and send a heartbeat to the server, after hot reload, the timer for the old socket does not work anymore, so the server disconnect the old socket after, say, 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from copying the SocketObj folder provided by the plugin, you might've missed merging the plugin's AppDelegate.m with your project's AppDelegate.m, and you also need to add `pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift', '~> 13.3.0'` on your project's podfile in `${PROJECT_ROOT}/ios/Podfile`

Then again, flutter_socket_io plugin seems to be tedious to set up. You may want to consider other socket plugins like [socket_io_client](https://pub.dev/packages/socket_io_client)